# How do you receive an event from AWS event bridge within a dotnet core lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, serverless-framework

I am unable to find an example of how to receive an event from AWS event bridge using dotnet core (3.1 preferably). Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Include in your project the package `Amazon.Lambda.CloudWatchEvents` and wrap your event with `CloudWatchEvent<T>`

```
 public void EventBridgeTriggerHandler(CloudWatchEvent<object> input, ILambdaContext context)
 {
    var payloadModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
    Console.WriteLine($"Input:..{payloadModel}");
 }
```

`object` can be substituted with your event class.